# Psycopg2 - Django 3.0.5

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to makemigrations in my project with Django using postgresql. But I have been having the following error:

```
(agenda_api) C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agendadj\agenda>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agendadj\agenda\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agendadj\agenda\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\felip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\felip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Escritorio\Managment\Cursos\Django\agenda_api\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 29, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
```

I tried to change the version of **psycopg2** but it did not work. I followed the suggestions on this issue https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1293 I tried to uninstall **psycopg2** and install **psycopg-binary** but i got other errors.

This is my requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.2.7
Django==3.0.5
django-model-utils==4.0.0
psycopg2==2.8.5
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.1
Unipath==1.1
```

Comment: I can't spot your python version. What version of python do you have?

Comment: I am using Python 3.10.7

Comment: Share your settings configurations

Answer (score 0):

Some users have opened [similar issues here](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues?q=is%3Aissue+django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured%3A+Error+loading+psycopg2+module%3A+DLL+load+failed+while+importing+_psycopg+is%3Aclosed) and they have all been closed. They seem to resolve issues raised quickly so you might want to begin by skimming through the suggestions raised there.

Also it appears you're using postgresql, if so, please ensure that your connection parameters are properly set up in your `settings.py` like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "mydatabase",
        "USER": "mydatabaseuser",
        "PASSWORD": "mypassword",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem following this 2 steps:

1. Install **psycopg2-binary** and **psycopg2** at the same time: *In the requirements.txt it is mentioned "psycopg2". This is recommended if you are working in windows. Instead if you are working in Linux or Mac, you should install psycopg2-binary. But this time I tried to install both.*

*The requirements.txt would look like this:*

```
asgiref==3.2.7
Django==3.0.5
django-model-utils==4.0.0
psycopg2==2.9.9
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.1
Unipath==1.1
```

2. Comment the line **USE_TZ = True** in the "**settings.py**": *I commented the line in my file "settings.py". Where the use of Time Zone is mentioned.*

```
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

#USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
```

doing this the project was compiled perfectly.